# Proof: Why are MM-1QFA strictly more powerful than MO-1QFA? (Quantum automata)

Tags: fl.formal-languages, quantum-computing, automata-theory

While dealing with quantum finite automata (QFA), I repeatedly come across the statement that *measure-many* QFA (MM-1QFA, [KW97](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/~watrous/Papers/QuantumFiniteAutomata.pdf)) are **strictly** more powerful than *measure-once* QFA (MO-1QFA, [MC97](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9707031)). More details are sufficiently summarized in this [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_finite_automata) if requested.

So far, I found a proof in [L19](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1308.3301.pdf) (p.5, prop.1) which shows that, for any MO-1QFA and any input string *w*, there is an MM-1QFA accepting *w* with the same probability (only bounded error considered here). Therefore, $\mathcal{L}$(MO-1QFA) = $\mathcal{L}$(MM-1QFA). However, I have not been able to find a proof showing that $\mathcal{L}$(MM-1QFA) > $\mathcal{L}$(MO-1QFA) indeed.

There are informal arguments by Brodsky and Pippenger [BP18](https://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/9903014.pdf) (p.9, start of sec.4), just saying that this is because MM-1QFA are allowed to terminate before reading the entire input string (due to their measurements after every transition). Furthermore, Ambainis and Freivalds [AF98](https://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/9802062.pdf) (end of p.3) say that "any finite language can be recognized by MM-1QFA, but no finite non-empty language can be recognized by MO-1QFA".

Though these claims seemed reasonable to me at first, I have failed to construct an example (let alone an idea for a general proof) that would make them clear to me. One issue is that I do not see, how a MM-1QFA would know "when to stop".

Based on all this, I would be glad if someone could help me to see why MM-1QFA are actually **strictly** more powerful than MO-1QFA.

Comment: Error? MO can throw false positives/negatives. MM uses additional queries to statistically certify the final result. That outcome can be wrong too, but its chance of failure is compounded toward zero with every measurement.

Comment: @Lem n, thanks for your comment. Intuitively this seems plausible. On the other hand, when regarding **general** 1QFA (where the transitions are not restricted to unitary operators but may be more general trace-preserving quantum operations), it was shown by [Li12](https://reader.elsevier.com/reader/sd/pii/S0304397511008917?token=E0FEE5882EE6944A728EE608C595AECD8D3F1727318C82AECEA16A0D7E4D6F57DDDAF9F8EA0A60BEE59484ED7C91A660) that multiple measurements do not increase the recognition power. So, why is this the case for the non-general version?